# Tab content disappeared after rotation inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabhost

I put a FragmentTabHost into a ViewPager, but the tab content has gone after I rotate the device. The tab content will come back if I click on another tab to refresh content. Is there anything wrong in my code? Please help me know.

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        View tabView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab, null);
        FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) tabView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"), TabContent1Fragment.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"), TabContent2Fragment.class, null);

        View page2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, null);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        List<View> list = new ArrayList<View>();
        list.add(page2);
        list.add(tabView);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new DemoPagerAdapter(list));
    }
}


public class TabContent1Fragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_content_1, null);
    }
}

public class DemoPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{
    private List<View> mModeViewPageList;

    public DemoPagerAdapter(List<View> modeViewPageList)
    {
       this.mModeViewPageList = modeViewPageList;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        container.addView(mModeViewPageList.get(position), 0);
        return mModeViewPageList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
    {
        container.removeView(mModeViewPageList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mModeViewPageList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o)
    {
        return view == o;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to my friend, finally I found the reason was that I used `PagerAdapter`.

When device is rotated, all views will be recreated. But without extra codes for fragment management, `PagerAdapter` is not able to mange the state of the fragments inside views (tab content fragments in realtabcontent in my case) and the child fragment of a view will disappear after rotation.

So I should change all views for `ViewPager` into fragments and use `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead.

One more thing, it should be used `getChildFragmentManager()` from Fragment in onCreateView instead of `getSupportFragmentManger()` from FragmentActivity to manage the child fragments in a fragment.

Comment: Thank you. getChildFragmentManager() did the trick for me. Such a life saviour

Comment: Replacement `activity.supportFragmentManager` on `childFragmentManager` helps me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to point out an important point in Light's answer. If you convert an `Activity` to a `Fragment` then you may have been using `getSupportFragmentManager`. When converting it, you may have changed it to `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`. It will seemingly work until you leave and return to the fragment, and you'll find some fragments missing until you scroll the pager.

The solution is to change `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` to `getChildFragmentManager()`.